# Using kubectl, how might one retrieve a list of packages installed in a container image?

Tags: linux, image, docker, kubernetes, kubectl

How would someone use `kubectl` to retrieve information about installed packages in a container image? For example, how would you find the version of an installed package? Or list all of the packages installed on the system?

I'm searching for a similar command to [docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/).

Comment: Can you explain the question bit more in detail? Or if you can add an example?

Comment: There is a Kubernetes cluster, it is necessary to collect information about applications running inside it. No direct access to docker containers. Maybe there is some kind of plugin for this?

Comment: No need for a plugin. `kubectl` supports this natively. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using [kubectl exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/#running-individual-commands-in-a-container). For example, here I am retrieving the version of `dnf` running in my example CentOS 7 container.

```
$> kubectl exec example-67575f5dfb-xw2qz -- dnf --version
4.2.7
  Installed: dnf-0:4.2.7-7.el8_1.noarch at Mon Jan 13 21:49:19 2020
  Built    : CentOS Buildsys <bugs@centos.org> at Thu Dec 19 15:44:23 2019

  Installed: rpm-0:4.14.2-25.el8.x86_64 at Mon Jan 13 21:49:16 2020
  Built    : CentOS Buildsys <bugs@centos.org> at Fri Nov  8 22:56:14 2019
```

Here's another example showing how to grab all of the installed packages on the image:

```
$> kubectl exec example-67575f5dfb-xw2qz -- dnf list all
Last metadata expiration check: 0:10:30 ago on Mon Mar 30 03:13:10 2020.
Installed Packages
acl.x86_64                                           2.2.53-1.el8                                      @System
audit-libs.x86_64                                    3.0-0.10.20180831git0047a6c.el8                   @System
basesystem.noarch                                    11-5.el8                                          @System
>SNIP<
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no equivalent to that. Kubernetes has a somewhat arms length relationship to containers. Most of the complex bits are delegates to the CRI plugin so K8s itself doesn’t know anything about images at all.

Comment: `kubectl exec` can execute commands against containers in pods. See my answer demonstrating a few examples with the `dnf` command requested by OP.

Comment: @TJZimmerman, I agree that what you mentioned in your answer can be used as a kind of workaround to get similar information but **kubernetes** and **docker** operate on quite a different level and @coderanger is 100% right in this case that *"there is no equivalent to do that"*. Note that in order to obtain such info in **kubernetes** you need to create a running `Pod` and only after that the information about istalled packages becomes available. **docker inspect** allows you to work directly with the image (you don't need for that a running container).

Comment: Fair, I've never used `docker inspect`. I've just had to `kubectl exec` into `bash` a few dozen times so I immediately knew an answer to this. I suppose it's semantical and therefore up to the person whether or not you consider first-tier API support as the qualifier for feature comparability. Compelling point with regards to the requirement of the container to be in use though.

Answer (score -2):

Please go through the kubectl docs. you should be able to interact with the cluster and able to collect required information.

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands

Comment: It's not really good answer etiquette to simply leave a link to documentation without providing contextual reference to the related information inside. For example, to look for the `exec` command as I noted  in my answer to this question. Here is a good thread on Meta about this:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer